# Can't move image with time delay

Tags: python, python-2.7, canvas, tkinter, delay

I'm trying to figure out how to make a scrolling image in python, but I got into some issues with delay.  I need the image to move *after* the canvas has rendered, and I also need it to move with a time delay.  Here is my current code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ImageTk
import time

def scrollToTop(imaget):
    for x in range(100, 20, -1):
        canvas.move(imaget, 0, -1)

t = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(t,height=256,width=256)
canvas.pack()

arrows = [1]
arrows[0] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="arrow.bmp")
image = canvas.create_image(20,100,image=arrows[0],tags="token")

t.mainloop();
scrollToTop(image);
```

I tried playing around where the `scrollToTop()` function was, and I also tried `time.delay(0.1)`, all to no avail.  I could try something like an `Update()` function, that measures the time passed from a "game time" variable...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: main loop `t.mainloop()` run till you close program so every instruction after `t.mainloop()` will be run after you close program.

You can use timer to call scrollToTop (for example) every 1 second (1000 millisecond)

```
from Tkinter import *
import ImageTk
import time

def scrollToTop():
    print "I'm in scrollToTop()"
    canvas.move(image, 0, -1)
    t.after(1000, scrollToTop)

t = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(t,height=256,width=256)
canvas.pack()

arrows = [1]
arrows[0] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="arrow.bmp")
image = canvas.create_image(20,100,image=arrows[0],tags="token")
scrollToTop()

t.mainloop();
```

**EDIT:**

`t.after()` require function name without `()` so if you need to run functiion with arguments use `lambda` function

```
from Tkinter import *
import ImageTk
import time

def scrollToTop(imaget):
    print "I'm in scrollToTop()"
    canvas.move(imaget, 0, -1)
    t.after(1000, lambda:scrollToTop(imaget))

t = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(t,height=256,width=256)
canvas.pack()

arrows = [1]
arrows[0] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="arrow.bmp")
image = canvas.create_image(20,100,image=arrows[0],tags="token")
scrollToTop(image)

t.mainloop();
```

Comment: Hey man, this is just perfect!  I didn't know TK had a method called after. "+1"

Comment: Okay, quick question:
1) Can I make this faster [I changed 1000 to 1 but still a bit too slow]? -- 

I also made the object delete when it scrolled to the top using if canvas.coords(imaget)[1] > 0:. ;)

Comment: Computer needs some time to move image and redraw it on screen - for example 100ms - so `scrollToTop` will be called no more than 10 times per second (1s = 1000ms ; 1000ms / 100ms = 10). if you set 1ms in `after()` you get only 10 moves per second (frames per second - FPS). To move faster you have to change values in `canvas.move()`. If you set `canvas.move(imaget, 0, -2)` image should move 2 times faster.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out later.  Thanks!  Still having a bit of problems because I need other functions to have delay, which can sometimes interfere with the other ones.  I'm working on a new frame-type system.